# Can Ubuntu adapt itself automatically when there is a hardware change?

Tags: hardware

I have questions about changing hardware of an Ubuntu system. If I make the following changes, will Ubuntu Linux adjusts itself automatically without the user going through re-installation of the OS?

1. If I change the RAM
2. I change the GPU
3. If I install Ubuntu on a SSD (SATA III or NVMe m.2) and later move it to a new computer with different CPU "and" motherboard.
4. If I change the CPU "or" the motherboard

Thanks.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but (1) changing ram will make no difference. (2) Changing GPU will often make no difference (you may need to add/remove kernel modules (drivers) to match changed gpu), *but it could require you to use a 'live' to do this*  (3&4) to me are the same, changing disks if UUID is used is no issue, but new mboard can mean device (sda9) numbers change. Changing motherboards I've had no issue with (usually), but I've also had issues; it depends on board type-differences.  In summary - most of the time it copes, but not all the time (*and these can fixed*)

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the graphics chip on the motherboard to drive the display and a dedicated GPU for something else. During installation, should I plug in the GPU as well? I changed Case 4 slightly.

Comment: @guiverc I would have sworn your comment was an answer waiting to be written! I await...

Comment: I didn't have time @GeorgeUdosen, when I returned (~an hour later) WinEunuuchs2Unix had written one, and I see no point for duplication, but thanks George

Comment: How about the keyboard? I am going to build the system soon. I prefer a wireless keyboard so I want to try it first. If it does not work, I will buy a wired keyboard. In this case, will Ubuntu be able to adapt this or I will have to reinstall the OS again? In the case of SSD, will Ubuntu has issue if I add 1 or 2 more SSD to the system later?

Answer (score 1):

There are four questions in one:

1. *If I change the RAM*

   - YES the new RAM is recognized.
2. *I change the GPU*

   - This will require installing new drivers. You need to post a question on your specific GPU. It's almost certain after changing GPU you'll have to interrupt `grub` boot with `e` and edit command line with `nomodeset`, or `nouveau.modeset=0`, or `nvidia.modeset=0` or `radeon.modeset=0`depending on what the old GPU was.
3. *If I install Ubuntu on a SSD (SATA III or NVMe m.2) and later move it to a new computer with different CPU and motherboard.*

   - Yes. But see summary below.
4. *If I change the CPU or the motherboard*

   - Yes. But a new CPU might require a microcode update for optimum performance. Note I think this is really the same as question 3, but in reverse.

#### Summary

Linux does things on the fly unlike Windows which locks you into drivers that must be installed during system setup. Any piece of hardware in Ubuntu though may require a `grub` override for successful booting. These you can fix on the fly though by pressing `e` in grub to edit the command line and pass the appropriate parameters to the kernel. Then after successful boot, make permanent changes in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update grub`.